# How do I access the value of a specific form field using react-hook-form-mui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am doing front-end development using react, typescript, and Material UI. To combine mui and react-hook-form, I quickly ended up using [dohomi/react-hook-form-mui](https://github.com/dohomi/react-hook-form-mui). Therefore, its overall structure is not yet fully understood.

I want to access and use the value of a specific field using `useWatch`, but I don't know how to do it. The documentation is very poor. I don't know whether `useWatch` should be imported from React-hook-form or React-hook-form-mui, and I don't know how to use it.

I tried something like below, and when the value changes, all components on the page re-render, not just that component. Additionally, the values ​​are not reflected when the form is submitted.

```js
import type { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { useForm, useWatch } from 'react-hook-form';
import { DateTimePickerElement, FormContainer } from 'react-hook-form-mui';

type FieldValues = {
  start: Dayjs | null;
  end: Dayjs | null;
};

export default function DateTimeForm() {
  const { control } = useForm<FieldValues>({ defaultValues: { start: null, end: null } });
  const start: Dayjs | null = useWatch({ control, name: 'start' });

  return (
    <FormContainer reValidateMode="onChange" mode="onChange">
      <DateTimePickerElement label="Start" name="start" control={control} required disablePast />
      <DateTimePickerElement label="End" name="end" minTime={start && start.add(1, 'hour')} required disablePast disableIgnoringDatePartForTimeValidation />
    </FormContainer>
  );
}
```

Is this normal behavior if I use `useWatch`? Or is there another correct way and am I missing it? Is it correct to use `useForm` and `control` this way? What am I missing?